# How to extract a variable from movie clip animation into main class public variable

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm new to AS3 so please be frindly :)

i develep a class with some public variables and private functions
and in the animation i made an eventLisener that call to function inside the frame coding.
i want the inside function to return a vale to a public variable in the main class.

this is the inside animation code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

var vector:b2Vec2 ;

pandaHold.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,getMouse);
pandaHold.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,getMouseOut);
function getMouse (e:MouseEvent):void{
    this.MouseX = mouseX;
    this.MouseY = mouseY;
}

function getMouseOut (e:MouseEvent):void{
    this.MouseXk = mouseX ;
    this.MouseYk = mouseY ;
    this.applyVector(makeVector());
}

function makeVector () : b2Vec2 {

    return( new b2Vec2 (this.MouseXk - this.MouseX,this.MouseY - this.MouseYk));

}
```

and here is the function in the main class

```
/*** apply Vector from movieClip ***/
 private function applyVector (newVector:b2Vec2):void {
       gravity = newVector;
}
```

Comment: whats going wrong?  Its hard to tell from your code example.  What did you expect?  What did you get? where?  What is a b2Vec2?  code for that?

Comment: thanks , i'm trying to make a vector in Box2D by using mouse event in  a movie clip.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your main document class as follows. Replace "MyDocumentClass" with the name of your document class (omit the .as).

Here is how to send your MovieClip object "vector" as an argument to your document class function "applyVector" from inside the MovieClip.

```
MyDocumentClass.applyVector(vector);
```